# JSF-Calling BackingBean method twice maintaining value of inputFileUpload

Tags: jsf

I am very new to JSF. I have the following requirement:
On click of a commandButton, call a backing bean method to check if there is some data present satisfying the condition. 
If yes, confirm from user for overwrite. 
If user says OK, call the same method of backing bean with some parameters set to tell the program to overwrite the data.

What I am doing is:
having action of the commandButton as the method name. 
in the backing bean method, check if we have come with certain condition, check if the data is already present.
If yes, go back to page and ask for confirmation.
If confirmed, call the click method of the button.

The problem is, when I come back to the page, the inputFileUpload component on the page loses its value.

What can I do to achieve this? Please help.

Comment: Open a confirmation dialog (without leaving the original page) , for example with the help of Primefaces http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/confirmDialog.jsf

Comment: @Daniel thanks for the input, but I do not have option to add another library in the existing code.

Comment: ok , so you can always do it your self... (in general , looks like you need to stay on the same page...)

Answer (score 0):

This is fully by HTML specification and completely outside control of JSF. It's by HTML specification for security reasons not possible to (re)display the value of a HTML input file field with a value coming from the server side. Otherwise a hazard scenario as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html/1696884#1696884) would be possible.

You need to redesign the form in such way that the input file field is not been updated during confirmation. You can use among others JavaScript/ajax for this: just submit the form by ajax and make sure that the input file field is not been updated on ajax response.